# how to get data from combobox (not seleted data, I need all data)

Tags: c#, combobox

Hellow I want to make a datatable by combobox

the combobox was made by datatable like this

`comboBox.DisplayMember = "text";`

`comboBox.ValueMember = "value";`

`comboBox.DataSource = dt;`

i found how to get a displaymember

`string cmbText = _cmb.GetItemText_cmb.Items[i]);`

but i can't found how to get valueMember from this combobox

how can i get it?

and sorry for terrible english.

---

Thanks guys i solve this like

1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _cmb.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var cmbDtRow = (DataRowView)_cmb.Items[i];
   string cmbText = cmbDtRow["text"].ToString();
   string cmbValue = cmbDtRow["value"].ToString();
}
```

2. 

```
foreach (DataRowView row in _cmb.Items)
{
   string cmbText = row[_cmb.DisplayMember].ToString();
   string cmbValue = row[_cmb.ValueMember].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This: `_cmb.GetItemText_cmb.Items[i]);` is not correct. You should have `string cmbText = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.Items[i]);`. If you just want the associated `Value` of the currently `SelectedItem`, then it's `comboBox.SelectedValue` (you have to cast it to the correct Type). If you want to loop the `Items` collection, cast each Items to `DataRowView`, e.g., `foreach (DataRowView row in comboBox.Items) { }`. Then the `Text` is `row[comboBox.DisplayMember]` and the `Value` is `row[comboBox.ValueMember]`

Comment: Note that you could loop the Rows collection of the underlying DataTable, which is `var dt = comboBox.DataSource as DataTable;`. Each item in the collection is a `DataRow`

Comment: Since you bound your data with `comboBox.DataSource = dt;`, the data you are looking for is in `dt`. No need to access the combobox. Don't misuse Controls to store data. Controls are for input/output.